# Insert id page on mysql table field

Tags: php, mysql

How do i insert the number(ID) of the curent page in a mysql data base?

I have this query:

```
     $page = $_REQUEST['id'];
            addslashes($page);
             $query = "insert into files 
(file_id,subid,fname,fdesc,tcid,floc) values ($newstd,'$page','" 
    . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['fname'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" 
    . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['fdesc'], ENT_QUOTES) 
    . "','" . $_SESSION['tcid'] . "','" 
    . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['floc'], ENT_QUOTES) . "')";
```

Page id is like index.php?ID=2

```
    I've tried this $page = $_GET['page'];
    addslashes($page);
    This gets the page value from the url, for example
 if you went to index.php?page=LOL it would return LOL 
into that $page variable. We now 
apply addslashes() to the $page variable
 for security reasons, as we are going to be using 
this in a MySQL query.
```

but is not working.

Table configuration:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `floc` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `fdesc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tcid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subid` text NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`Subid` is the page number.

Comment: Can you share your table configuration?

Comment: What is that datatype of the column in which you wants to insert this page id?

Comment: You should have change subid datatype from int to text

Comment: in query you have used $PAGEID but variable you are creating is $page

Comment: I changed from int to text and it's the same. In int he displayed 0 and now nothing.

Comment: can you print or echo your query? so that we can get idea about error.

Answer (score 2):

use `$page = $_REQUEST['ID'];` instead of `$page = $_GET['page'];`

Comment: i think so  $PAGEID should be replaced with  $page in query.